# Copy array of pointers and skip certain index

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to make a remove function for an array class that uses an array of pointers to store objects.

So what I've got is a list of pointers to objects declared like so:

```
objname* list = new objname[100];
```

Note, its declared as a member of a class, lets call it myClass.

What I want is to make a function to myClass that takes an index as a parameter, and removes the object from list on that index. Here's what I've got and what I want to do.

```
void myClass::remove(int index)
{
    objname* temp = new objname[listlen]; //creating a temporary list to copy values from the "main" list.

    //want to copy elements from 0 to index in "this->list" and store inside temp, then skip one element and copy the rest.

}
```

There might be a better way to get this functionality and if so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use arrays and are not yet allowed to use std::vector then you can do the task by applying two times standard algorithm std::copy

For example, (I suppose that listlen is the size of the original array)

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
objname* temp = new objname[listlen - 1];
std::copy( std::next( list + index ), list + listlen, 
           std::copy( list, list + index, temp ) );
```

Expression std::next( list + index ) can be substituted for list + index + 1 provided that for the both expressions index is less than listlen.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but this gives me an error when calling the remove function saying "Error 1 error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'"

Comment: Use this macro as the message suggest. In fact it is not an error. It is a warning. In the DEBUG mode the compiler checks all iterators but for arrays it can check them.

Comment: Yea, I can do that but will it prevent me from getting other maybe useful error messages in the future or is it "safe" to just ignore all of these warnings?

Comment: I think you can use directive #define and then #undef for this macro name.

Comment: Done some research and it seems like that should be the solution, however the error(warning) remains after defining the macro, even tried turning off warnings in project properties and the no change..

Comment: Worked when adding this line as project settings instead of using #define, will accept answer, thanks alot.

Answer (score 5):

> What I want is to make a function to myClass that takes an index as a parameter, and removes the object from list on that index.

You can do this easily with an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
#include <vector>   // for std::vector
#include <iterator> // for std::next

std::vector<objname> v;

void myClass::remove(int index)
{
  v.erase(std::next(v.begin(), index));
}
```

Obviously you should first check that the vector is large enough for `index`.

But if what you really want to do is copy a portion of one array into another, again, you can easily do this with standard library components:

```
std::vector<objname> v = ...;
std::vector<objname> temp(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), index));
```

Here, `temp` will contain copies of the first `index` elements of `v`.

Comment: Yes, I've read about those but isn't arrays more effective? even if in this case it wouldn't make a difference to use a vector instead assume its a massive array of big objects, is there a way to do it using arrays? I was mainly thinking of something like std::copy, then skip an element and copy everything after into a temp array, but couldn't get that to work properly..

Comment: @Jacco There is no reason for arrays to be "more effective". But f you want a copy, then you can do that. Just copy from one vector into another.